# AngularJS: Unexpected token '>' error in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, safari

Everything is working fine with chrome and firefox, but when i try to access site with safari older versions i get this message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'(anonymous function) @ VMundefined
```

this is happening on this line of code

```
<section class="company container">
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are attempting to use an arrow function in a browser that didn't support them, i.e.

```
() => 'val';
```

You'll need to use a long hand function, or transpile with Babel, TypeScript or similar.

```
function () { return 'val'; }
```

Comment: Can you expand your code example a bit, so I can see that line in context?

Comment: ok Thanks man, there was a couple of () => 'val'; on javascript files! All I needed to do is disable bundling and change all the () => 'val'; to function () { return 'val'; }